# Sum of data in R

Tags: r, sum

This is my data

> **rank = 10, 1, 6, 28, 29, 12, 2, ...**

How can I get the sum of the length as follow by using R ?

**SumOfRank = 10, 11, 17, 45, 74, 86, 88, ...**

which is `SumOfRank = rank[i] + rank[i - 1]`?

---

[image]

Comment: You are asking for cumulated sum. Function `cumsum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `cumsum` is what you are looking for:

```
cumsum(SumOfRank)
[1] 10 11 17 45 74 86 88
```